# How do I exclude List B from List A in Kusto?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, azure-monitoring

I would like to get an overview of recent SpecialEvents, the ones that already have a comment named 'Skip' need to be excluded from list A. Since comments is an array I can't simply put everything in one query with a where clause (it will not process Comments since it only contains value: '[]').
How do I combine these two tables (Show everything from List A except the ones that are in List B)?

// List A: Show all Event created less than 1 hour ago
SpecialEvent
| where TimeGenerated < ago(1h)
| distinct uniqueNumber
| project uniqueNumber

// List B: Don't add the ones that contain 'skip'
SpecialEvent
| mvexpand parsejson(Comments)
| extend commentMsg = Comments.message
| where commentMsg contains 'SKIP'
| distinct uniqueNumber
| project uniqueNumber

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use the `!in()` operator or an anti-`join`.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/inoperator
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator

For example:

```
let list_a = 
   SpecialEvent 
   | where TimeGenerated < ago(1h) 
   | distinct uniqueNumber
;
SpecialEvent 
| where uniqueNumber !in(list_a)
| mv-expand parsejson(Comments) // you could also use 'mv-apply' and perform the filters on 'SKIP' under that scope
| extend commentMsg = Comments.message
| where commentMsg contains 'SKIP'
| distinct uniqueNumber
```